# Htaccess directory password Drupal

Tags: .htaccess, drupal, passwords

And sorry if this question has already been answered. But I'm trying to add a folder to my Drupal 7 installation that can be accessed only via password. I have created the folder in my FTP (and named it folder), but unfortunately I can't access this folder. I'd like the folder to look like this (like in Wordpress)
[image]

But instead I get "Page isn't working".

Br. Five

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are running Apache, try adding a `.htaccess` file to that folder with the following content:

```
Options +Indexes
```

When you want to password protect the directory with `.htaccess` you'll also have to add this:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "My Protected Area"
AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That did it!

Comment: Actually the first Options +Indexes showed all the files in folder, but for some reason I can only get the password protection work in the root .htaccess file. I'm pretty sure there is some setting wrong in that file, but I don't know what.

Comment: then please show ur your file.. or ask a new question because your original problem (displaying the files) is solved.